# Issue on remove/replace symbols and character codes in String

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, ejs

I want to pass an object `dataO` from Node.js/Express/EJS to client side.
so on node JS side script tag :

```
var dataO =  {"first":[20000, 14000, 12000, 15000, 18000, 19000, 22000], "second":[12000, 11000, 18000, 12000, 19000, 14000, 26000]};
var dataP = JSON.stringify(dataO);
app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.render("index", {sStatus, dataP});
  });
```

and trying to `JSON.parse` in client side:

```
var dataX =  JSON.parse("<%= dataP %>");
```

But on client side I got Error: *Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token & in JSON at position 1*
and `dataP` value is : `"{&#34;first&#34;:[20000,14000,12000,15000,18000,19000,22000],&#34;second&#34;:[12000,11000,18000,12000,19000,14000,26000]}"`
I removed `&#34` but still got the same error.

Where is the poop guys?
Thanks

Comment: In a `<script>` tag, you cannot/should not html-entity-escape characters. The only thing you need to escape there is `</script>`. Also try not to emit a JSON string (that you'd need to js-string-escape) and parse that on the client, but simply emit a JS object literal right away. See ejs docs for how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. The problem was I tried to send data directly to client which is wrong in many ways, I had to use `XMLHttpRequest` so I simply solve with this example:

Client Code:

```
$("#myBtn").click( function () {
    console.log("Button Pressed");
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var params = "123";

    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            console.log(this.responseText); //And this catch sent JSON from Server.
        }
    };

    xhttp.open('POST', './data', true);
    xhttp.send(); //can sent anything from here to Server!
    
});
```

And the code in Nodejs side is:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
var ejs = require('ejs');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.set('views' , './views')
app.set('view engine' , 'ejs')

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

var dataX =  {"first":[20000, 14000, 12000, 15000, 18000, 19000, 22000], "second":[12000, 11000, 18000, 12000, 19000, 14000, 26000]};

app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.render("index");
  }); 

  app.post("/data", function(req,res){
    console.log("render pushed");
    res.json(dataX); //pass data to client, just remember don't make any other callbacks.
  })

  app.listen(3200 , () => console.log('Listening on port 3200'))
```

That's all. Beginner issues ;-)